# In a Python string, how to replace character "œ" to "£"

Tags: python, string, replace, character, special-characters

I am parsing a CSV file into Python but need to replace the œ character with £, how do I achieve this as adding:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
```

does not work.

I see the "œ" sign in the CSV file, when parsed by Python it reads as "œ", so I need this "œ" replaced with "£" by Python.

The CSV is opened using: `data = [row for row in csv.reader(open(CSVfilename, 'rU'))]` I then have: `testVar = (data[someRow][someCol]).replace(",", "")` which essentially removes commas, but when I add: `replace.("œ", "£")` it does not work

Comment: Show us the code that you're using to parse the CSV

Comment: What do you mean with replace? Can you see the pound sign properly when opening in an editor but not when loading in python? Or do you see the hex value for "œ" in the text file and you want to replace it with pound sign? Please be very specific about the issue since many things can factor what is happening here.

Comment: i see the "œ" sign in the CSV file, when parsed by python it reads as "œ", so i need this "œ" replaced with "£" by python.

Comment: Read my answer, but I do think you are not opening the csv file with the proper encoding...

Comment: the CSV is opened using: 
data = [row for row in csv.reader(open(CSVfilename, 'rU'))]
i then have:
testVar = (data[someRow][someCol]).replace(",", "")
which essentially removes commas, but when i add:
replace.("œ", "£")
it does not work

Comment: @coolcoder Please edit your post to include the information in your comment.

Comment: If you encode your python file in cp1252 then it is very likely that the code point for 'œ' will not match what is in your CSV unless it is also encoded in cp1252. Maybe you should consider writing your script in unicode and converting the csv to unicode.

Comment: @coolcoder, you are not helping by saying "it does not work". Show us exceptions or non expected results.

Answer (score 0):

The `coding: cp1252` is how the python file you are working on is encoded, which has nothing to do with the encoding of your CSV file.

I guess your problem is that you are not opening the csv taking into account the right encoding, and therefore you are getting weird characters like `œ` instead of `£`. If this is the problem: find out how the file was encoded, and open it with that encoding.

If however, you are opening properly the file, and you want to change the contents from `œ` to `£`, you just have to perform a string replacement. Example as following (naive approach, not very memory efficient, and asssuming utf-8)

```
with open(csv_path) as csv_file:
    csv_contents = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
    csv_contents = csv_contents.replace(u'œ', u'£')
    # Do something with your csv...
```